# How do I have this code adjusted using js, html and css to have a default collapsed view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the full code and it has js, css and html. I got this from an online snippet and I am not good with Javascript. Please help!!!

I have this posed on my home page and taking up the space, would be great to have it all collapsed.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
    $this.closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
    $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  } else {
    $this.closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
    $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-heading span {
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
          <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h3>
          <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 3</h3>
          <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 4</h3>
          <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: throw this at the end of your script `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.panel-heading span.clickable').closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown(); });`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work.

Comment: i didn't actually run it or you code i was just guessing. if you make your code into a runnable [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or use the code editor on the question editing-thingy so we can see what you mean it will make it easier to debug.

Comment: I am new to this world, let me try and see if I can present this in a better way. Sorry, please beat with me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s7moin/vsa828p0/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add this in your css: `.closeThisPanel{ display:none; }`
2. Add the `closeThisPanel` class to the `panel-body` div.
3. Add the `panel-collapsed` class the the `clickable` span.
4. Change the icon from `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up` to `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
    $this.closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
    $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  } else {
    $this.closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
    $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
    $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-heading span {
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.closeThisPanel{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 2</h3>
          <span class="pull-right clickable panel-collapsed"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body closeThisPanel">Panel content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```